# Здраствуйте. Не понимаю как решить задачу на СИ

Tags: c, операторы, координаты

**Заданы координаты вершин четырехугольника. Вывести их в порядке обхода по часовой стрелке.**
Главная проблема в том, что в задаче можно использовать только условные операторы, массивы и функции нельзя использовать, задача из вуза для закрепления темы про условные операторы, не понимаю как можно вывести координаты по часовой при помощи условных операторов.

- Комментарий преподавателя:
  Предлагаю 2 варианта.

1. Найдите координаты центра множества - среднее арифметическое по x и y, она будет внутри четырехугольника (рекомендую сразу рисовать). Если от этой точки построить отрезки (векторы) до каждой вершины, то можно найти углы наклона этих отрезков. Теперь берем эти углы от большего к меньшему (находим самый большой, потом и оставшихся следующий самый большой и потом наибольший из двух оставшихся) и выводим координаты вершин в этом же порядке.
2. Берем первую точку в качестве начала, а остальные три - как концы векторов. Находим попарные векторные произведения и так определяем, какой вектор левее всех, его конец - это вторая точка. Аналогично из оставшихся двух определяем левый (третья точка) и остается последняя точка.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Думаю, что функции `printf` тоже разрешены :)

Comment: Кроме условных операторов потребуется ещё умножение, сложение и вычитание.

Comment: А ничего что просто 4 вершин в общем случае недостаточно что бы задать четырёхугольник однозначно?

Comment: Ну и непонятно почему тема «условные операторы» мешает использовать массивы и функции.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, хм, почему координаты 4 вершин четырехугольник не зададут однозначно?! ... если все вершины соединяются отрезками. Чего ещё не хватает?

Comment: @Volk есть такая фигура - восьмёрка 8

Comment: На тот момент мы не проходили массивы и функции, душный препод попался, требует использовать в решении только условные операторы

Comment: Преподаватель предлагает складывать координаты (для получения средней точки) с помощью условных операторов?

Comment: получается так, у меня уже на самом деле даже идей нет как эту задачу можно решить

Comment: Спросите у преподавателя можно ли складывать, вычитать и умножать числа?

Comment: да, можно, надо было изначально об этом написать

Comment: @AlexeyTen, понял, это самопересекающаяся которая, но её и по часовой стрелке не обойдешь. Подозреваю, что тут не имеется ввиду такая экзотика.

Comment: @Volk можно и без самопересечений https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZLI3.png

Comment: @AlexeyTen,  благодарю. Совершенно верно! Туповат :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В предположении что все точки - вершины выпуклого четырёхугольника, задачу решает сортировка трёх точек по углу вокруг первой:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3;
    scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d", &x0, &y0, &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2, &x3, &y3);

    if ((x1 - x0) * (y2 - y0) - (x2 - x0) * (y1 - y0) > 0) {
        int tmp = x1;
        x1 = x2;
        x2 = tmp;
        tmp = y1;
        y1 = y2;
        y2 = tmp;
    }

    if ((x1 - x0) * (y3 - y0) - (x3 - x0) * (y1 - y0) > 0) {
        int tmp = x1;
        x1 = x3;
        x3 = tmp;
        tmp = y1;
        y1 = y3;
        y3 = tmp;
    }

    if ((x2 - x0) * (y3 - y0) - (x3 - x0) * (y2 - y0) > 0) {
        int tmp = x2;
        x2 = x3;
        x3 = tmp;
        tmp = y2;
        y2 = y3;
        y3 = tmp;
    }
    printf("%d %d\n%d %d\n%d %d\n%d %d\n", x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
}
```

Comment: спасибо огромное, спас ситуацию

Comment: Ох, ну тут уж вообще автор мозговых усилий не приложил, даже при наличии указаний препода.

Comment: @MBo, не удержался. :(